# Multiple remote Safari instances on a single macOS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-session, safaridriver, safari, remote-webdriver

I need to test multiple separate browser sessions simultaneously (to simulate remote collaboration). This works easily in in Chrome and Firefox but not so in Safari. I keep getting the following error message:

> Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.

I tried running multiple instances of the standalone Selenium server on different ports but this also did not help:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4445
```

And neither did running it from different user accounts. Is there any way I can do this without having to run multiple instances of the full OS?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not possible at the moment (or in the near future from the tone of the following statement).
From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari:

> #### One Session at a Time, to Mimic User Interaction
>
> Only one Safari browser instance can be active at any given time, and only one WebDriver session at a time can be attached to the browser instance. These constraints ensure that the simulated behavior (mouse, keyboard, touch, and so forth) accurately reflects what a user can do in a macOS windowing environment and prevents tests from competing with each other for window and keyboard focus.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was to use @fixture annotation and set the scope to function.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Safari


@fixture(scope='function')
def browser():
    browser = Safari()
    return browser
```